# input button not working in angularjs when only button is there in body

Tags: angularjs, submit-button

As my title says, i was creating a login form and following was my html. but submit button is not working.

```
<body ng-controller="AdminController">
    <div class="container">
    <section id="content">
        <form action="">
            <h1>Log In </h1>
            <div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username" required="" id="vxUserName" ng-model="UserName" />
            </div>
           <div>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" required="" id="vxUserPass" ng-model="UserPassword" />
            </div>

            <div style="padding-left:10px;padding-bottom:70px;padding-top:30px">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Log in" id="vxLogin" ng-click="CheckUser()" />

            </div>
        </form><!-- form -->

    </section><!-- content -->
</div>

</body>
```

Here is my angularjs.

```
app.controller('AdminController', function ($scope, $http, $location, $timeout, $filter) {

    var SelectedPackages = "";
    $scope.ContactDetails = [];
    var SelectedEnquiry = sessionStorage.getItem("_SelectedEnquiry");
    $scope.setId = function (setal) {

        alert(SelectedEnquiry);
    };
    $scope.CheckUser = function () {
        alert("a");
        sessionStorage.setItem("_OwnAccessCount", "0");
        sessionStorage.setItem("_OwnAccessUsed", "0");
        debugger;
        $http.get("ws/ws_HolidayPackages.asmx/CheckUser?&_UserName=" + $scope.UserName + "&_Password=" + $scope.UserPassword)

       .success(function (data) {

           sessionStorage.setItem("_UserPassword", $scope.UserPassword);
           var userPassword = sessionStorage.getItem("_UserPassword");

           debugger;
           data = data.replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>', '');
           data = data.replace('<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">', '');
           data = data.replace('</string>', '');
```

.....
......
.....
as button click was not working. i tried everything like changing giving input a type, changing ng-click to ng-submit, giving $event.stopPropagation(); with ng-click but my checkuser method not getting called. i also remived all html and only left input button but still it is not working.

```
<body ng-controller="AdminController">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Log in" id="vxLogin" ng-click="CheckUser();" />
</body>
```

Comment: how do you decide its not working?

Comment: i shall try to create and add reference here.

Comment: please send your skype id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are missing the ng-app directive in your HTML,

```
<body ng-app="yourAppname" ng-controller="AdminController">
```